# MySQL Connection in Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I want to run this command in Ubuntu

```
mysql -uroot -p password
```

I am getting this error

> Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
> '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Comment: What is the output of the logs ? Is `MySQL` running ?

Comment: You have plenty of  related problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Can%27t+connect+to+local+MySQL+server+through+socket)

Answer (score 0):

## Unable to connect to local MySQL server through socket

Recently, there was a problem with the installed sudo database on my ubuntu system. I was forced to reinstall it. After the reinstallation started, I used the mysql command client to connect and the following message appeared:

```
[LING mysql]$ mysql -u root -p
 
Enter password: 
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

My my.cnf is as follows:

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
 
user=mysql
# Default to using old password format for compatibility with mysql 3.x
# clients (those using the mysqlclient10 compatibility package).
old_passwords=1
 
[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
port=3307
```

Enter / var / lib / mysql and discover that mysql.sock exists, but mysqld.sock does not exist in / var / run / mysqld. If you have a clever idea, you can use /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock via soft link:

```
[ROOT mysqld]$ ln -s /var/lib/mysql/mysql/mysql.sock /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[ROOT mysqld]$ mysqld_safe --log-error=/var/lib/mysql/error.log &
```

Make the link and start mysql, check the error.log as follows:

```
[ROOT mysql]$ more error.log 
 
InnoDB: The log sequence number in ibdata files does not match
InnoDB: the log sequence number in the ib_logfiles!
100313 10:48:12  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
100313 10:48:12  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 43655
100313 10:48:12 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.0.51a-3ubuntu5.5'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3307  (Ubuntu)
[ROOT mysql]$
```

Re-link, success!